# How to distinguish whether the environment is dev or prod in angular15

Tags: angular

Angular15 cancels the environment.prod.ts file by default.

How do I distinguish between dev and prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';


if(isDevMode()) {
console.log('Your app is running in dev mode', isDevMode())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is true that `environment.prod.ts` is not generated by default, Angular let you the responsibility to configure them as you like. For example, if you need any polyfill, you’ll need to add it yourself. So u still can add `environment.prod.ts` or any other type of environments.